# Is implementing a singleton using an auto-property a good idea?

Tags: c#, singleton, automatic-properties

I recently found out about auto-properties and like them quite a lot. At this moment I am trying to use them everywhere where I can. Not really to just be able to use them everywhere, but more to see how well they work in most situations.

Now I am making a singleton and thought:"Hey, let's try auto-properties here as well".

```
public class MySingleton
{
    public static MySingleton MySingleton { get; private set; }

    private MySingleton() {}

    static MySingleton() { MySingleton = new MySingleton(); }
}
```

So my question is: "Is it a good idea to implement a singleton like this?"

I am not asking whether a singleton in general is a good idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wouldn't personally do that. I don't like using automatically implemented properties with a private setter that you never call where *really* you want a read-only property backed by a read-only variable. It's only one more line of code to be more explicit about what you mean:

```
public sealed class MySingleton
{
    private static readonly MySingleton mySingleton;
    public static MySingleton MySingleton { get { return mySingleton; } }

    private MySingleton() {}

    static MySingleton() { mySingleton = new MySingleton(); }
}
```

This way no-one's even *tempted* to change the singleton class to reassign either the property or the variable, because the compiler will stop them. They'd have to add a setter and/or make the variable non-readonly, which is a bigger change - one which hopefully they'd reconsider.

In other words:

- Yes, it will work.
- No, I don't think it's a good idea.

As of C# 6, this is easier with read-only automatically implemented properties though:

```
public sealed class MySingleton
{
    public static MySingleton MySingleton { get; } = new MySingleton();    
    private MySingleton() {}         
    static MySingleton() {}
}
```

Comment: I strongly disagree. Auto-properties were invented to make code more succinct, which makes code more readable. The argument that it's a little harder for others to mess up your design is not very convincing IMHO.

Comment: @Philippe: Auto-properties were invented to make code more succinct *where the replacement code is equivalent to the original*. There's no such equivalence here: you're replacing a read-only property with a read-write one, even though it's got a private setter. This may seem trivial, but I rather like my code to express my intentions - and my intention here would be that the value can only be set once. The automatically implemented property expresses a different intention.

Comment: You have a point about the "intention" of the setter, but in the end, to the consumer of the class, there is no difference whatsoever. Having an auto-property with a private setter is excactly the same as having a read-only property with a private backing field. Sure, it compiles to different code, but it's essentially the same from the point of view of the consumer of the class. Now I have to slap myself, because I've never liked auto-properties and now I'm defending its use (but that's a topic for another question I guess)

Comment: @Philippe: So as long as the API is all right to the *consumer*, it doesn't matter what the implementation is like? What about the maintainer? I like my code to document intention to the next person who's going to look at the source code, not just consumers.

Comment: In the case of a well-known pattern, the "intent" is usually very clear, so I don't think it's an issue here. My point really is: "Less code" is usually "Better code", as long as it results in better readability. But I don't want to start an endless argument. Your points are valid, but in this specific case, I think the OP's code is more readable.

Comment: Hello - the new syntactic sugar in C# makes it OK to se the auto property like that, doesn't it? `public static SomeSingleton Instance { get; } = new SomeSingleton();`

Comment: @Bartosz: Yes, that would be fine as of C# 6. Will edit.

Comment: @JonSkeet does the auto-property interfere with thread safety/laziness? Just reading through your _C# in Depth_ companion website and looking at [Solution no. 4](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

Comment: @Thomas: Nope, it shouldn't do - it's a simple property backed by a read-only field.

Answer (score 11):

I would approach this from a slightly different direction than Jon. *Regardless* of whether the object is a singleton, *is it logically best modeled as a property in the first place?*

Properties are supposed to represent... properties. (Captain Obvious strikes again!) You know. Color. Length. Height. Name. Parent. All stuff that you would logically consider to be a property of a thing.

I cannot conceive of a *property* of an object which is logically a *singleton*. Maybe you've come up with a scenario that I haven't thought of; I haven't had any Diet Dr. Pepper yet this morning. But I am suspicious that this is an abuse of the model semantics.

Can you describe what the singleton is, and why you believe it to be a property of something?

All that said, I myself use this pattern frequently; usually like this:

```
class ImmutableStack<T>
{
    private static readonly ImmutableStack<T> emptystack = whatever;
    public static ImmutableStack<T> Empty { get { return emptystack; } }
    ...
```

Is "Empty" logically a property of an immutable stack?  No. Here the compelling benefit of being able to say

```
var stack = ImmutableStack<int>.Empty;
```

trumps my desire for properties to logically be properties.  Saying

```
var stack = ImmutableStack<int>.GetEmpty();
```

just seems weird.

Whether it is better in this case to have a readonly field and a regular property, or a static ctor and an autoprop, seems like less of an interesting question than whether to make it a property in the first place. In a "purist" mood I would likely side with Jon and make it a readonly field. But I also frequently use the pattern of making autoprops with private setters for logically immutable objects, just out of laziness.

How's that for taking all sides of a question?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I never really considered properties in that manner. For me they have always just been a replacement for accessor methods. In a way I viewed accessor methods as a way to improve upon public fields (partially hide, put in interface, add some checking info). And then properties to be able to get a more intuitive way than getters and setters. So for me a property never has to logically be a property of the things the class represents. For me a property is just how a field looks from the outside.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the benefit of property-like syntax in your `ImmutableStack<int>.Empty` example? I'd like to better understand what benefit you achieve here, particularly since in LINQ `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` is similar to the type of syntax you avoid in that example.

Comment: @LBushkin -- I suppose "Empty" vs "Empty()" vs "GetEmpty()" are all pretty small differences. I think "compelling benefit" was an exaggeration! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why this wouldn't be correct. After all, auto-properties are just syntactic sugar for accessors for a private (compiler-generated) backing field.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I don't see any problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

Auto property? No, I wouldn't but using a setter on a singleton, yes I did. I think you want more control over it than an auto property will give you.

... constructive feedback is more than welcome here, please. This feels like a brave (or foolish) move in this esteemed company ...

My scenario, a WPF app that has a Current Project than can be loaded and saved. The current project settings are used all over the application...

- in WPF bindings in the UI so the user can change the settings, hence the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
- I also use [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) but that doesn't do static property changes, hence `NotifyStaticPropertyChanged`.
- `INotifyPropertyChanged` works fine with WPF bindings on the singleton's properties.
- An instance of the `Settings` is [de]serialized using JSON.NET, hence the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on the singleton. I validate it before loading it into the singleton or saving it to disk.
- the logger is [Serilog](https://serilog.net/). You log stuff, right?
- the singleton is `public` with a `public` getter because WPF bindings only work on public properties. The `internal` setter doesn't affect it. All the properties of `Settings` are public for WPF binding.

I left all the "noise" in the code because some may find it useful.

```cs
class Settings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static Settings _currentSettings = new Settings();

    /// <summary> The one and only Current Settings that is the current Project. </summary>
    [JsonIgnore] // so it isn't serialized by JSON.NET
    public static Settings CurrentSettings //  http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx 
    {
        get { return _currentSettings; }

        // setter is to load new settings into the current settings (using JSON.NET). Hey, it works. Probably not thread-safe.
        internal set 
        {
            Log.Verbose("CurrentSettings was reset. Project Name: {projectName}", value.ProjectName);
            _currentSettings = value;
            _currentSettings.IsChanged = false;
            NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("CurrentSettings");
        }
    }

    // http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties
    /// <summary> Fires when the Curent CurrentTvCadSettings is loaded with new settings
    ///           Event queue for all listeners interested in StaticPropertyChanged events. </summary>
    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // various instance properties including ....

    public string ProjectName {get; set;}

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsChanged { get; set; } 
}
```

usage to set the singleton to a newly loaded project, `settings` is simply

```
Settings settings = new Settings();
// load, save, deserialize, set properties, go nuts
Settings.CurrentSettings = settings;
```

The setter probably isn't thread-safe but I only set it in one place from the UI thread so I'm not scared. You could make it thread safe following the esteemed advice at  http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

I realise the OP didn't ask about WPF but I think it's relevant to show why you may want to set a singleton. I did it because it is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap up + alternative syntax with lambda style (>= C# 6) aka computed property (aka expression-bodied member):

The code is functionally fully equivalent to the answer of Jon Skeet, here again with "Instance". I don´t expect kudos for this, but I think this updated wrapup with explanation at one place is it worth, because this C#6 question and answers extend the old closed thread where variations of Singleton have been discussed.

You could argue the automatic-property-style with an explicitly missing set expresses clearer the intent of a read-only property, but in the end it is style based, and both styles are common in modern C#.

```
public sealed class MySingleton
{
    public static MySingleton Instance => new MySingleton(); // Assure that instantiation is only done once (because of static property) and in threadsafe way, and as this is an alternative style for a readonly-property, there is no setter
    private MySingleton() {} // Assure, that instantiation cannot be done from outside the class        
    static MySingleton() {} // Assure partly lazyness, see below     
}
```

Here is all detail and historical reference at one place:

Discussion about lazyness: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx
Simplified summary: The above implementation behaves lazy as long as no other static fields/properties are introduced in the class.
(But this is an area which can be .NET implementation-dependent.)

Discussion concerning different implementations of Singleton and thread safety (older C# styles):
http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Original thread (closed):
[Singleton Pattern for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667024/singleton-pattern-for-c-sharp)