# Example of a singleton class with a dictionary of BitmapImages

Tags: c#, dictionary, singleton, bitmapimage

I know this is a simple question, but I can't find an example anywhere. Please think of this as helping out a newbie. I need to create a singleton class so I can access a dictionary of BitmapImages across multiple files.

The dictionary is:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, BitmapImage> PlantImageDictionary;
```

Could someone please post an example of how to create/instantiate this?
Could someone please post an example of how such a dictionary would be called?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you need an implementation of the singleton (anti)pattern?? It's a topic beaten to death on the internet (lazy, lock, double lock....). As an aside, whatever implementation you choose, make sure it returns a read only dictionary.

Comment: Why do I want a read only dictionary? I have to add to it.

Comment: Are you going to be modifying it from different threads? The `Dictionary<K,V>` class isn't thread-safe, so you'll either need to wrap every access in a lock, or use [`ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) instead.

Comment: I'm opening an XML file in one thread and loading the images and creating the keys and then using it another thread to display the correct images.

Comment: I need to access a dictionary across multiple C# files. It can't be done (to the best of my knowledge) by using a global. Do you know of any other way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Singleton Pattern for C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667024/singleton-pattern-for-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

If you're just going to be reading from the dictionary, you don't need `ConcurrentDictionary`. In fact, I wouldn't recommend exposing a `Dictionary` at all. Rather, I'd expose the minimum number of methods you need. If all you want is the ability to look something up by key, then supply just that method.

Here's a very simple singleton that will do what you're asking for.

```
public sealed class ImageCache
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Bitmap> Images;

    static ImageCache()
    {
        Images = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
        // load XML file here and add images to dictionary
        // You'll want to get the name of the file from an application setting.
    }

    public static bool TryGetImage(string key, out Bitmap bmp)
    {
        return Images.TryGetValue(key, out bmp);
    }
}
```

You probably should spend some time studying the Singleton pattern and looking at alternatives. Whereas the above will do the job, it's not the best practice. One glaring problem, for example, is that it needs outside knowledge of the XML file's location, making it somewhat difficult to fit into a testing framework. There are better alternatives, but this should get you started.

Comment: First, thanks for replying and the information! Maybe I'm going at this the wrong way. I just need to access a dictionary of bitmapimages across a bunch of C# files in the same project. I also need to access some big byte arrays across multiple C# files in the same project. I can't use the global trick. What do you suggest?