# Alternative for static classes implementing interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, static

For few reasons, static classes cannot implement interfaces, and I wonder what is the best practice for implementing two static classes that has the same methods with different implementations.

First class:

```
public static class MyStaticClass1
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do Something here...
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
public static class MyStaticClass2
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do Something here...
    }
}
```

The methods must be static since they are using the `[DllImport]` attribute which can be used on static methods only.

Depending on some runtime condition, In some runs I'll be using `MyStaticClass1`, and `MyStaticClass2` on others, but not both in the same run.

Ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a singleton in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155688/what-is-a-singleton-in-c) and [Singleton Pattern for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667024/singleton-pattern-for-c-sharp) and [Thread Safe C# Singleton Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316406/thread-safe-c-sharp-singleton-pattern)

Comment: Suggested duplicates are for the question title: "*Alternative for static classes implementing interface*"... but regarding the body, I don't see the relation with DllImport and no interface is mentioned. However, you can redirect any interface property and method implemention to static members, thus the singleton will be a wrapper to statics.

Comment: @OlivierRogier the DllImport is mentioned to avoid solutions that will omit the static methods, and interface is mentioned in the first line of the question.

Comment: @.FriendOfFriend Is the suggested design suitable?

Comment: @OlivierRogier No since Static member cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Comment: @.FriendOfFriend Of course yes, I do this every hour of code, sometimes to solve cases like this one as well as having many instances accessing common static members. [static (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

Comment: @OlivierRogier (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0176?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0176))

Comment: @.FriendOfFriend Yes! To access a public static member `MyMember` of `MyClass` from the outside, you must use `MyClass.MyMember` and not `myInstance.MyMember`... And from the inside, you simply write `MyMember`. Thus you can provide instance members to implement interface that wraps static members. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yea, I see what you mean and that actually means to delegate a call to a matching static one. That means that every method will have two signatures, one which isn't static for outside calls, and an internal static one. I'd rather avoid the duplication.

Comment: @.FriendOfFriend No other way: static classes cannot implement interfaces, and static methods of non-static classes cannot be interface implementations. I know it is annoying, therefore the only solution is that, as I know: an instance wrapper to implement interfaces, toward statics, and once the hard work will be done, you'll be ok and happy. I don't think writing an answer is necessary, and if you want only one instance, singleton is what you need.