# Auto-property initializer Singleton implementation

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, automatic-properties, c#-6.0

So, with the brand new C# 6 we got those neat auto-property initializers. I thought I might as well take advantage of these to make more concise singletons than ever. Apparently [someone else](http://www.harrysmemo.com/post/124283867727/singleton-pattern-in-c) got that idea, too.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    public static Singleton Instance { get; } = new Singleton();
    private Singleton() { /* some initialization code */ }
}
```

My questions are:

1. How thread-safe it is?
2. How lazy it is, or when the instance is actually created? (not a priority, but it would be good for future reference)
3. Is it a good idea overall?

(it might look similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117241/is-implementing-a-singleton-using-an-auto-property-a-good-idea), but it's not)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code will be expanded to the following:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton <Instance>k__BackingField = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton Instance { get { return <Instance>k__BackingField; } }
    private Singleton() { /* some initialization code */ }
}
```

(`<Instance>k__BackingField` is the [unspeakable name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2508828/41071) of the compiler-generated field.)

So, the properties of your code will be exactly the same as of the code above. Namely, this pattern is thread-safe and it can be a good idea, depending on circumstances.

Assuming you're not accessing any other static members of this type before accessing `Instance`, then the exact degree of laziness is up to the runtime. Commonly, it will be something like "the instance is created the first time a method that *could* access `Instance` is JIT-compiled", but you don't have any guarantee about this.

If you want to make sure that the instance is created just before `Instance` is accessed for the first time, add an empty static constructor to your class. (This can have a small negative effect on performance, but that probably won't matter to you.)

Since most of this is not really specific to C# 6, a good source of further information would be Jon Skeet's articles about [singletons](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) and [static constructors/type initializers](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BeforeFieldInit.aspx).